# Spring service periodic task

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Lets suppose there is spring boot web app with 2 classes mapped as @Controller and @Service. Service is injected into controller's field. I need my service to run task once a second to update some external data. Is there something wrong with this code?

```
@Component
public class MyService implements Runnable{
    public MyService() {
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                // operations here
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you seen https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/?

Comment: You can do that using spring quartz

Answer (score 0):

Though there are a lot of ways of creating a task, using job or spring task scheduler, below is one straightforward way.

Below task will run every second.

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("hello");
        }
    }, 0, 1000); // o is delay time after which it starts, 1000 is time interval
```

Or you may want to refer [here](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-task-scheduler) to implement spring task scheduler .